# Expert-level tutorials on LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc, documentation

This question was posted on the LO Facebook page:

Folk, Any one has Libre office expert level tutorial for CALC ? I need it to present in my company since we are migrating to MS Office to Libre Office 3.4. Urgent help require.

This documentation (http://www.libreoffice.org/get-help/documentation/#cg) isn't enough

Comment: Try the page here (It's for OpenOffice, but it'll still work) http://www.learnopenoffice.org/calccontents.htm

Comment: I am curious as to why the document you point to is not enough, the Libre Office calc manual seem to be a fairly advanced document. Do you want to teach macros? What are your main objectives?

Comment: Originally someone else posted this question here: https://www.facebook.com/libreoffice.org , but I thought getting an answer here might help others, too.

I asked him regarding what exactly is missing in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help someone...

https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/images/6/6d/0300CG3-CalcGuideLibO3.pdf

400 pages manual including advanced topics.